# How to get ant build to work in Eclipse Android Plugin?

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, configuration, build

When I press the run button in Eclipse, it brings me to a window that says, "Create, manage, and run configurations." What am I supposed to do here? I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have installed the [android sdk](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) for eclipse?

If yes then, before you can start, you have to create an avd (android virtual device). For more information should [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) link be helpul.

**EDIT:**

[image]

1. Right click on Android Application (in the left menu)
2. Click on new
3. Give a name and select the project

[image]

4.
Select the created avd

5.
Click apply

6.
Click run

Comment: I've done everything. I just dont know how to set up the ant build configuration to compile and run it.

Comment: Why do you want to set up the ant build? you don't need this for the compilation. and also not to let the program run in the avd...

Comment: @user1608145 is your question answered with my edited answer, or do you still need more information?